# New to Java and Keep Getting Syntax Error

Tags: java

I’m new to coding and I keep getting a syntax error on token “.”, ;
in line 21, 22, and 23 (the System.out.println). I can figure out we’re exactly the error is?

```
// calculator for the price of milk
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DairyCalculator
{

 public static void main( String [] args)
 {
    double cartonhold = 3.78;
    double productioncost = 0.38;
    double cartonprofit = 0.27;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print( "Enter how many liters of milk was produced; "); // input
    double produced = sc.nextInt();

    double cartonsneeded = produced / cartonhold;


     int System.out.println( "Milk cartons needed" = cartonsneeded);
     double System.out.println("Cost of production" = produced * productioncost);
     double System.out.println("Profit" = produced * cartonprofit);

    sc.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Whats the `int` and `double` supposed to do in the `System.out.println` lines? Also the `=` is wrong. Time to read a good Java book.

Comment: First, you should fix the indentation of your code, because what you have is horrendous to read.

Comment: ... and to warm up before reading the book please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ... and to warm up before reading the book please read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have already defined the datatypes for produced,cartoonprofit etc so you don't need to define them again when you are trying to print them

Comment: Sara - If an answer below answers your question, please consider to upvote and also accept the answer

Answer (score 3):

You do not need the `int` `double` etc before the `System.out...` statements, and also the format of your statements is incorrect, see below

```
System.out.println("Milk cartons needed " + cartonsneeded);
System.out.println("Cost of production " + (produced * productioncost));
System.out.println("Profit " + (produced * cartonprofit));
```

Also you may want to revisit whether you want to hold the variables as `int` or `double` values.

Answer (score 1):

you need to go through Java language's syntax and basics first.

As from your code it seems you are new to Java language.

you can make below correction in your code :

```
System.out.println( "Milk cartons needed ="+ cartonsneeded);
            System.out.println("Cost of production ="+ produced * productioncost);
         System.out.println("Profit = "+produced * cartonprofit);
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code as

```
// calculator for the price of milk
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DairyCalculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double cartonhold = 3.78;
    double productioncost = 0.38;
    double cartonprofit = 0.27;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter how many liters of milk was produced; "); // input
    double produced = sc.nextInt();

    double cartonsneeded = produced / cartonhold;

    System.out.println("Milk cartons needed = " + cartonsneeded);
    System.out.println("Cost of production = " + produced * productioncost);
    System.out.println("Profit = " + produced * cartonprofit);

    sc.close();
}
}
```

you donot need int and double before System.out.. and also read more about java syntax.
You can use '+' operator to concat string

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in every `System.out.println()` statement. This statement is used to print the output on the console. So you can not declare it as `int`, `double` or any other datatype. So there is a simple syntax error in each print statement. Also the `=` is an assignment operator. If you want to print it as console output you must enclose it within inverted commas. And use `+` operator for concatenating two strings. So the correct code would be as follows :

```
// calculator for the price of milk
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DairyCalculator {
    public static void main( String [] args) {
        double cartonhold = 3.78;
        double productioncost = 0.38;
        double cartonprofit = 0.27;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print( "Enter how many liters of milk was produced; "); // input
        double produced = sc.nextInt();

        double cartonsneeded = produced / cartonhold;

        System.out.println("Milk cartons needed = " + cartonsneeded);
        System.out.println("Cost of production = " + produced * productioncost);
        System.out.println("Profit = " + produced * cartonprofit);

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use data type before `System.out.println` as it is just used for printing purpose and data type are used for variable declaration.

In "" Quotes, you write whatever message you want to print ,i.e. ,the Hard-coded Message that you want to give.

`+` operator after "" is used to Concatenate the value of required object to the Hard-coded Message.

So for this, you use `+` operator and write the object name after it which will print the hard-coded message and value of the object that you want to print.